# How to use `pd.read_sql` using `mysql.connector`

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I know we can read `sql` using different packages than `mysql.connector` but since I only know `mysql.connector`, I want to use it to read a table from `sql` and save it as `dataframe` in pandas.
I have the following as my code.

```py
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    passwd = '*',
    database = 'mydatabase'
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM my table"
df = pd.read_sql(query, mycursor)
```

I am not sure about the last line, that is `df = pd.read_sql(query, mycursor)`. I think I am missing some arguments here.
Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TRY THIS CODE

```
import mysql.connector as sql

import pandas as pd

db_connection = sql.connect(host='hostname', database='db_name', 
user='username', password='password')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table_name', con=db_connection)
```

Comment: i get UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  df = pd.read_sql_query(q, mydb)

Comment: @Raksha This is just a warning and probably works.  SQLAlchemy has problems with Python 3

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace [`df = pd.read_sql(query, mycursor)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) with [`df = pd.read_sql_query(query, mydb)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas-read-sql-query) because you want to make a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html) using a query (make sure to pass `mydb` not `mycursor`).

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'. It does not work.